# Recommendations for scalable architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, architecture, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have 3 containerized applications. All these applications are a simple python script that calls an api at different times. For example, App1: calls every hour, App2: calls every 30 mins, and App3: calls every minute. Right now we have an ec2 instance for each application, which is ok because I need the applications to run on different AWS EC2 Instances because I don’t want my IP Blacklisted. But now how would I go about scaling an application? For example, I need 3 instances of app 1.

Im currently using Terraform to create the EC2 instances and while that can work I don't know how to go about automating updating the images on each EC2 instance.

I tried using AWS ECS to scale the container but this requires that it shares IP address ( I would like for these applications to live in different VMS(EC2 Instances.), so that the IP does not have a problem getting blacklisted.) with the other applications and I don’t want that.

What tools or architecture can best help me accomplish the scaling of these applications?

Comment: How simple the applications are? 
As an option if they can be easily converted to Lambda functions I think the bounding of Lambda + CloudWatch (for scheduling crons) should solve the case with scalability. Here should be a clue how to have distinct IPs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291517/4644059

If you need to keep docker you most likely have to stay with EC2/ECS. You can check options that spin up multiple EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, I would suggest AWS Fargate ECS + Cloudwatch events cron triggers (Scheduled Fargate ECS tasks).

Fargate instances have `awsvpc` network mode by default, which means if you run them in public subnet with public IP allocation, each container instance will retrieve unique public IP (via dedicated automatically attached ENI - Elastic Network Interface).

Additionally, running tasks on Fargate will allow you to utilize much more convenient docker packaging of your applications while keeping management & operating requirements low - as Fargate is a Server-less container scheduler, and it requires less effort than operating AWS EC2 instances.

You will need 3 ECS resources :

1. cluster
2. template resource for container definition
3. task definition resource

and 3 CloudWatch resources:

1. `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`
2. `aws_cloudwatch_event_target`
3. `aws_cloudwatch_log_group`

in Terraform to make it work, + ECR repo/s for storing image artifacts.