# How to run an ECS task from AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have created an ECS task definition and that runs successfully using AWS console and AWS CLI. Multiple instances of these tasks would run in a cluster. These are long-running tasks (few months to years).

I'm trying to run an instance of this task using the AWS Lambda function but it's not working. No error is thrown and a task does not run. I have added AdministratorAccess to the execution role used by the lambda. The VPC, subnet group, and security groups are configured in Lambda (tab Configuration > VPC)

Goal is to run the task and not wait for response (as these are long running tasks):

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ecs = new aws.ECS();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
     
   var params = {
        cluster: "default", 
        count: 1,
       launchType: "FARGATE",
       networkConfiguration: { 
         awsvpcConfiguration: { 
         assignPublicIp: "ENABLED",
         securityGroups: [ "sg-79002b" ],
         subnets: [ "subnet-f4b4bf" ]
        }
       },
    taskDefinition: "ecs-test-job-TestTaskDefinition-RgKHGrRzWZOq:1"
 };
 ecs.runTask(params, function(err) {
      if (err) { console.warn('error: ', "Error while starting task: " + err); }
 });
};
```

Response:

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 3f89e3d7-b997-4cda-a939-1ad806812c31 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 3f89e3d7-b997-4cda-a939-1ad806812c31
REPORT RequestId: 3f89e3d7-b997-4cda-a939-1ad806812c31  Duration: 50.20 ms  Billed Duration: 51 ms  Memory Size: 1280 MB    Max Memory Used: 87 MB  Init Duration: 417.57 ms
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async function exports.handler is returning before your `ecs.runTask` promise is being resolved try wrapping it like:

```
var myprom = ecs.runTask(params).promise();
var result = await myprom;  //Old syntax is myprom.then(()=>{})
```

[Try this code for checking if Lambda can connect to the internet.](https://github.com/mihaerzen/lambda-internet-access-checker)

Lambda on a public subnet that is connected to Internet Gateway won't have access to the internet.

[Excerpt from another answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50280780/2801909).

> For Lambda to have access to the internet via VPC it should be in the
> Private Subnet with NAT Gateway attached.

> Attach NAT Gateway instead of igw-xxxxxx in route table of your
> current subnet

Comment: I had tried await as well but as these are long-running tasks we do not expect a response.
Await times out after 15 minutes (`{"errorType":"TimeoutError","errorMessage":"connect ETIMEDOUT 52.95.114.96:443","code":"TimeoutError","message":"connect ETIMEDOUT 52.95.114.96:443","errno":-110,"syscall":"connect"..,"stack":["Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.95.114.96:443","    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)"]}
END`)

Comment: Are your Lambdas deployed in a VPC that can access the internet?

Comment: You nailed it. Lambda was on a public subnet but needed to be on a private subnet with NAT Gateway attached not Internet Gateway. I updated your answer with my findings. Thank you, David.